# Output another array inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop like so:

```
$test_array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

foreach($categories as $category)
{ 
    echo $category; // outputs cat one cat two cat three cat four cat five etc
    echo $test_array; // outputs Array Array Array Array Array
}
```

and this displays fine and dandy.

But I also want to output the **test_array** array too but when I do, it says 'Array Array Array Array Array Array ' along with my categories :(

How do I get the test_array to display in my foreach loop too?

Comment: You mean display all the elements each time, or one per category?

Comment: Could you post the code you used that outputted 'Array Array etc'?

Comment: @cHao display the categories array and the test_array both

Comment: @Keith: That doesn't really answer the question.  You want something like "cat one 1 2 3 4 5 cat two 1 2 3 4 5", or "cat one cat two.... 1 2 3 4 5"?

Comment: @cHao: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797436/output-another-array-inside-a-foreach-loop#answer-5797623 like this, this seems to work great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your answer is what you want, and if you're not doing odd stuff with array indexes, then you could say

```
foreach ($categories as $index => $category)
{
      echo $category, $test_array[$index];
}
```

Note, though, that this depends on both arrays having sequential, numeric indexes.  Arrays defined like `array(2, 5, 10)` work fine, as do arrays built up by `$arr[] = $some_value;`.  But if you're using non-numeric keys or adding them out of order, you may have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function.

Comment: Or better yet, [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) so you can see types and values that type juggle to empty strings (like `false`)

Comment: Anyway I can output the test_array in a "normal way"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this nested loop. I think it'll do what you want.

```
$loopCount = 0;
    foreach($categories as $category) { 
      echo $category;
      if($count <5) {          
       foreach($test as $someInt) {
         echo $someInt;
         $count++;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, anyway to limit the test_array being called 5 times?

Comment: See the edit above. I added a loop counter. Is that what you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [var_dump](https://www.php.net/var_dump) personally.  Good luck!

Comment: Anyway I can output the test_array in a "normal way"?

Comment: you can output a <pre> tag before your call to var_dump. This will make the output preformatted. Also, if you "view source" in the browser, it'll show you a nice preformatted output.

Answer (score 0):

Think I came up with a solution:

```
$test_array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$i=-1;
foreach($categories as $category)
{ 
    $i++;
    echo $category; // outputs cat one cat two cat three cat four cat five etc
    echo $test_array[$i]; // outputs Array Array Array Array Array
}
```

This works, but is it ok?

Comment: Depends on result which you want to achieve :)